# How to use restricted boltzman machine to classify?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, data-mining

I was reading about restricted boltzman machines which is an algorithm used on deep learning. I dont finish to understand how do a RBM can be used to classification. Could anybody provide me a example of clssifying with this algorithm?.

From wikipedia:

> RBMs have found applications in dimensionality reduction,
>   classification, collaborative filtering, feature learning and topic
>   modelling. They can be trained in either supervised or unsupervised
>   ways, depending on the task.[1]

[1] Larochelle, H.; Bengio, Y. (2008). "Classification using discriminative restricted Boltzmann machines". Proceedings of the 25th international conference on Machine learning - ICML '08. p. 536. doi:10.1145/1390156.1390224. ISBN 9781605582054. edit

Answer (score 2):

RBM is **not** a classification model, it is a model for **unsupervised learning**. There are at least two possible classification-related applications:

- In deep learning, RBMs are used as **preprocessing** units, while on the top of them you still built some "simple" linear model (like logistic regression, perceptron or svm)
- In some side works (by Hinton in particular) you can create two RBMs stacks, and connect them with one layer of RBM on top, where one stack is feeded with inputs, and the second one with labels. This way RBM during autoaussociation learning actually models the input->labels mapping (as well as the other way around)